# Как определить установлен ли пакет?

Tags: unix, solaris, ssh, linux

Необходимо определить установлены ли пакеты c `zlib` и `openssl`. `aptitude` отсутствует и невозможно установить пока что по определенным причинам, поэтому вариант, предлагавшийся на http://admin.hashcode.ru/questions/5794/linux-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B2-nexenta отпадает, да и `zlib` и `openssl` могли устанавливаться вручную. Эти программы необходимы для установки `openssh` (см. ftp://ftp.ca.openbsd.org/pub/OpenBSD/OpenSSH/portable/INSTALL), поэтому конечно можно просто попытаться установить его и если система выдаст ошибку на отсутствие таких программ, то значит, они не установлены, но хотелось бы это выяснить все таки перед попыткой установки `openssh`.

P.S. В результате выполнения скрипта `./configure` я получил следующий результат (помогите расшифровать относительно вопроса, который я задал, да и вообще необходима информация, что из указанного на ftp://ftp.ca.openbsd.org/pub/OpenBSD/OpenSSH/portable/INSTALL необходимо установить, я новичок в `Linux`, поэтому прошу отнестись с пониманием)

```
checking for gcc... gccchecking whether the C compiler works... yeschecking for C compiler default output file name... a.outchecking for suffix of executables... checking whether we are cross compiling... nochecking for suffix of object files... ochecking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yeschecking whether gcc accepts -g... yeschecking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none neededchecking build system type... i386-pc-solaris2.11checking host system type... i386-pc-solaris2.11checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -Echecking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/gnu/bin/grepchecking for egrep... /usr/gnu/bin/grep -Echecking for ANSI C header files... yeschecking for sys/types.h... yeschecking for sys/stat.h... yeschecking for stdlib.h... yeschecking for string.h... yeschecking for memory.h... yeschecking for strings.h... yeschecking for inttypes.h... yeschecking for stdint.h... yeschecking for unistd.h... yeschecking whether byte ordering is bigendian... nochecking for gawk... nochecking for mawk... nochecking for nawk... nawkchecking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -Echecking for ranlib... ranlibchecking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/gnu/bin/install -cchecking for egrep... (cached) /usr/gnu/bin/grep -Echecking for ar... /usr/gnu/bin/archecking for cat... /usr/gnu/bin/catchecking for kill... /usr/gnu/bin/killchecking for perl5... nochecking for perl... /usr/bin/perlchecking for sed... /usr/gnu/bin/sedchecking for ent... nochecking for bash... /usr/bin/bashchecking for ksh... (cached) /usr/bin/bashchecking for sh... (cached) /usr/bin/bashchecking for sh... /usr/gnu/bin/shchecking for groff... /usr/bin/groffchecking for nroff... /usr/gnu/bin/nroffchecking for mandoc... nochecking for groupadd... /usr/sbin/groupaddchecking for useradd... /usr/sbin/useraddchecking for pkgmk... yeschecking for special C compiler options needed for large files... nochecking for _FILE_OFFSET_BITS value needed for large files... 64checking for login... /usr/bin/loginchecking for passwd... /usr/bin/passwdchecking for inline... inlinechecking whether LLONG_MAX is declared... yeschecking whether SYSTR_POLICY_KILL is declared... nochecking whether RLIMIT_NPROC is declared... nochecking whether PR_SET_NO_NEW_PRIVS is declared... nochecking if gcc supports -Wall... yeschecking if gcc supports -Wpointer-arith... yeschecking if gcc supports -Wuninitialized... yeschecking if gcc supports -Wsign-compare... yeschecking if gcc supports -Wformat-security... yeschecking if gcc supports -Wpointer-sign... yeschecking if gcc supports -Wunused-result... nochecking if gcc supports -fno-strict-aliasing... yeschecking if gcc supports -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2... yeschecking gcc version... 4.4.4checking if gcc accepts -fno-builtin-memset... yeschecking if gcc supports -fstack-protector-all... yeschecking if -fstack-protector-all works... yeschecking bstring.h usability... nochecking bstring.h presence... nochecking for bstring.h... nochecking crypt.h usability... yeschecking crypt.h presence... yeschecking for crypt.h... yeschecking crypto/sha2.h usability... nochecking crypto/sha2.h presence... nochecking for crypto/sha2.h... nochecking dirent.h usability... yeschecking dirent.h presence... yeschecking for dirent.h... yeschecking endian.h usability... nochecking endian.h presence... nochecking for endian.h... nochecking features.h usability... nochecking features.h presence... nochecking for features.h... nochecking fcntl.h usability... yeschecking fcntl.h presence... yeschecking for fcntl.h... yeschecking floatingpoint.h usability... nochecking floatingpoint.h presence... nochecking for floatingpoint.h... nochecking getopt.h usability... yeschecking getopt.h presence... yeschecking for getopt.h... yeschecking glob.h usability... yeschecking glob.h presence... yeschecking for glob.h... yeschecking ia.h usability... nochecking ia.h presence... nochecking for ia.h... nochecking iaf.h usability... nochecking iaf.h presence... nochecking for iaf.h... nochecking limits.h usability... yeschecking limits.h presence... yeschecking for limits.h... yeschecking login.h usability... nochecking login.h presence... nochecking for login.h... nochecking maillock.h usability... yeschecking maillock.h presence... yeschecking for maillock.h... yeschecking ndir.h usability... nochecking ndir.h presence... nochecking for ndir.h... nochecking net/if_tun.h usability... nochecking net/if_tun.h presence... nochecking for net/if_tun.h... nochecking netdb.h usability... yeschecking netdb.h presence... yeschecking for netdb.h... yeschecking netgroup.h usability... nochecking netgroup.h presence... nochecking for netgroup.h... nochecking pam/pam_appl.h usability... nochecking pam/pam_appl.h presence... nochecking for pam/pam_appl.h... nochecking paths.h usability... yeschecking paths.h presence... yeschecking for paths.h... yeschecking poll.h usability... yeschecking poll.h presence... yeschecking for poll.h... yeschecking pty.h usability... nochecking pty.h presence... nochecking for pty.h... nochecking readpassphrase.h usability... nochecking readpassphrase.h presence... nochecking for readpassphrase.h... nochecking rpc/types.h usability... yeschecking rpc/types.h presence... yeschecking for rpc/types.h... yeschecking security/pam_appl.h usability... yeschecking security/pam_appl.h presence... yeschecking for security/pam_appl.h... yeschecking sha2.h usability... yeschecking sha2.h presence... yeschecking for sha2.h... yeschecking shadow.h usability... yeschecking shadow.h presence... yeschecking for shadow.h... yeschecking stddef.h usability... yeschecking stddef.h presence... yeschecking for stddef.h... yeschecking for stdint.h... (cached) yeschecking for string.h... (cached) yeschecking for strings.h... (cached) yeschecking sys/audit.h usability... nochecking sys/audit.h presence... nochecking for sys/audit.h... nochecking sys/bitypes.h usability... nochecking sys/bitypes.h presence... nochecking for sys/bitypes.h... nochecking sys/bsdtty.h usability... nochecking sys/bsdtty.h presence... nochecking for sys/bsdtty.h... nochecking sys/cdefs.h usability... nochecking sys/cdefs.h presence... nochecking for sys/cdefs.h... nochecking sys/dir.h usability... nochecking sys/dir.h presence... nochecking for sys/dir.h... nochecking sys/mman.h usability... yeschecking sys/mman.h presence... yeschecking for sys/mman.h... yeschecking sys/ndir.h usability... nochecking sys/ndir.h presence... nochecking for sys/ndir.h... nochecking sys/poll.h usability... yeschecking sys/poll.h presence... yeschecking for sys/poll.h... yeschecking sys/prctl.h usability... nochecking sys/prctl.h presence... nochecking for sys/prctl.h... nochecking sys/pstat.h usability... nochecking sys/pstat.h presence... nochecking for sys/pstat.h... nochecking sys/select.h usability... yeschecking sys/select.h presence... yeschecking for sys/select.h... yeschecking for sys/stat.h... (cached) yeschecking sys/stream.h usability... yeschecking sys/stream.h presence... yeschecking for sys/stream.h... yeschecking sys/stropts.h usability... yeschecking sys/stropts.h presence... yeschecking for sys/stropts.h... yeschecking sys/strtio.h usability... nochecking sys/strtio.h presence... nochecking for sys/strtio.h... nochecking sys/statvfs.h usability... yeschecking sys/statvfs.h presence... yeschecking for sys/statvfs.h... yeschecking sys/sysmacros.h usability... yeschecking sys/sysmacros.h presence... yeschecking for sys/sysmacros.h... yeschecking sys/time.h usability... yeschecking sys/time.h presence... yeschecking for sys/time.h... yeschecking sys/timers.h usability... nochecking sys/timers.h presence... nochecking for sys/timers.h... nochecking sys/un.h usability... yeschecking sys/un.h presence... yeschecking for sys/un.h... yeschecking time.h usability... yeschecking time.h presence... yeschecking for time.h... yeschecking tmpdir.h usability... nochecking tmpdir.h presence... nochecking for tmpdir.h... nochecking ttyent.h usability... nochecking ttyent.h presence... nochecking for ttyent.h... nochecking ucred.h usability... yeschecking ucred.h presence... yeschecking for ucred.h... yeschecking for unistd.h... (cached) yeschecking usersec.h usability... nochecking usersec.h presence... nochecking for usersec.h... nochecking util.h usability... nochecking util.h presence... nochecking for util.h... nochecking utime.h usability... yeschecking utime.h presence... yeschecking for utime.h... yeschecking utmp.h usability... yeschecking utmp.h presence... yeschecking for utmp.h... yeschecking utmpx.h usability... yeschecking utmpx.h presence... yeschecking for utmpx.h... yeschecking vis.h usability... nochecking vis.h presence... nochecking for vis.h... nochecking for lastlog.h... yeschecking for sys/ptms.h... yeschecking for login_cap.h... nochecking for sys/mount.h... yeschecking for obsolete utmp and wtmp in solaris2.x... yeschecking compiler and flags for sanity... yeschecking for yp_match... nochecking for yp_match in -lnsl... yeschecking for setsockopt... nochecking for setsockopt in -lsocket... yeschecking for dirname... yeschecking libgen.h usability... yeschecking libgen.h presence... yeschecking for libgen.h... yeschecking for getspnam... yeschecking for library containing basename... none requiredchecking zlib.h usability... yeschecking zlib.h presence... yeschecking for zlib.h... yeschecking for deflate in -lz... yeschecking for possibly buggy zlib... nochecking for strcasecmp... yeschecking for utimes... yeschecking libutil.h usability... nochecking libutil.h presence... nochecking for libutil.h... nochecking for library containing fmt_scaled... nochecking for library containing login... nochecking for library containing logout... nochecking for library containing logwtmp... nochecking for library containing openpty... nochecking for library containing updwtmp... none requiredchecking for fmt_scaled... nochecking for login... nochecking for logout... nochecking for openpty... nochecking for updwtmp... yeschecking for logwtmp... nochecking for strftime... yeschecking for GLOB_ALTDIRFUNC support... nochecking for gl_matchc field in glob_t... nochecking for gl_statv and GLOB_KEEPSTAT extensions for glob... nochecking whether GLOB_NOMATCH is declared... yeschecking whether struct dirent allocates space for d_name... nochecking for /proc/pid/fd directory... yeschecking for arc4random... nochecking for arc4random_buf... nochecking for arc4random_uniform... nochecking for asprintf... yeschecking for b64_ntop... nochecking for __b64_ntop... nochecking for b64_pton... nochecking for __b64_pton... nochecking for bcopy... yeschecking for bindresvport_sa... nochecking for clock... yeschecking for closefrom... yeschecking for dirfd... yeschecking for fchmod... yeschecking for fchown... yeschecking for freeaddrinfo... yeschecking for fstatvfs... yeschecking for futimes... nochecking for getaddrinfo... yeschecking for getcwd... yeschecking for getgrouplist... nochecking for getnameinfo... yeschecking for getopt... yeschecking for getpeereid... nochecking for getpeerucred... yeschecking for _getpty... nochecking for getrlimit... yeschecking for getttyent... nochecking for glob... yeschecking for group_from_gid... nochecking for inet_aton... yeschecking for inet_ntoa... yeschecking for inet_ntop... yeschecking for innetgr... yeschecking for login_getcapbool... nochecking for md5_crypt... nochecking for memmove... yeschecking for mkdtemp... yeschecking for mmap... yeschecking for ngetaddrinfo... nochecking for nsleep... nochecking for ogetaddrinfo... nochecking for openlog_r... nochecking for poll... yeschecking for prctl... nochecking for pstat... nochecking for readpassphrase... nochecking for realpath... yeschecking for recvmsg... yeschecking for rresvport_af... yeschecking for sendmsg... yeschecking for setdtablesize... nochecking for setegid... yeschecking for setenv... yeschecking for seteuid... yeschecking for setgroupent... nochecking for setgroups... yeschecking for setlinebuf... yeschecking for setlogin... nochecking for setpassent... nochecking for setpcred... nochecking for setproctitle... nochecking for setregid... yeschecking for setreuid... yeschecking for setrlimit... yeschecking for setsid... yeschecking for setvbuf... yeschecking for sigaction... yeschecking for sigvec... nochecking for snprintf... yeschecking for socketpair... yeschecking for statfs... yeschecking for statvfs... yeschecking for strdup... yeschecking for strerror... yeschecking for strlcat... yeschecking for strlcpy... yeschecking for strmode... nochecking for strnlen... yeschecking for strnvis... nochecking for strptime... yeschecking for strtonum... nochecking for strtoll... yeschecking for strtoul... yeschecking for swap32... nochecking for sysconf... yeschecking for tcgetpgrp... yeschecking for timingsafe_bcmp... nochecking for truncate... yeschecking for unsetenv... yeschecking for updwtmpx... yeschecking for user_from_uid... nochecking for vasprintf... yeschecking for vhangup... yeschecking for vsnprintf... yeschecking for waitpid... yeschecking for library containing dlopen... none requiredchecking for gai_strerror... yeschecking for library containing nanosleep... none requiredchecking whether getrusage is declared... nochecking whether strsep is declared... yeschecking for strsep... yeschecking whether tcsendbreak is declared... yeschecking whether h_errno is declared... yeschecking whether SHUT_RD is declared... yeschecking whether O_NONBLOCK is declared... yeschecking whether writev is declared... yeschecking whether MAXSYMLINKS is declared... yeschecking whether offsetof is declared... yeschecking for setresuid... nochecking for setresgid... nochecking for gettimeofday... yeschecking for time... yeschecking for endutent... yeschecking for getutent... yeschecking for getutid... yeschecking for getutline... yeschecking for pututline... yeschecking for setutent... yeschecking for utmpname... yeschecking for endutxent... yeschecking for getutxent... yeschecking for getutxid... yeschecking for getutxline... yeschecking for getutxuser... nochecking for pututxline... yeschecking for setutxdb... nochecking for setutxent... yeschecking for utmpxname... yeschecking for getlastlogxbyname... nochecking for daemon... yeschecking for getpagesize... yeschecking whether snprintf correctly terminates long strings... yeschecking whether snprintf can declare const char *fmt... yeschecking for (overly) strict mkstemp... nochecking whether getpgrp requires zero arguments... yeschecking OpenSSL header version... 1000004f (OpenSSL 1.0.0d 8 Feb 2011)checking OpenSSL library version... 1000004f (OpenSSL 1.0.0d 8 Feb 2011)checking whether OpenSSL's headers match the library... yeschecking if programs using OpenSSL functions will link... yeschecking for RSA_generate_key_ex... yeschecking for DSA_generate_parameters_ex... yeschecking for BN_is_prime_ex... yeschecking for RSA_get_default_method... yeschecking for HMAC_CTX_init... yeschecking whether OpenSSL has crippled AES support... nochecking if EVP_DigestUpdate returns an int... yeschecking for SHA256_Update... yeschecking for EVP_sha256... yeschecking whether OpenSSL has complete ECC support... nochecking for ia_openinfo in -liaf... nochecking whether OpenSSL's PRNG is internally seeded... yeschecking if select works with descriptor rlimit... nochecking if setrlimit RLIMIT_FSIZE works... yeschecking for long long... yeschecking for unsigned long long... yeschecking for long double... yeschecking size of short int... 2checking size of int... 4checking size of long int... 4checking size of long long int... 8checking for u_int type... yeschecking for intXX_t types... yeschecking for int64_t type... yeschecking for u_intXX_t types... nochecking for u_intXX_t types in sys/socket.h... nochecking for u_int64_t types... nochecking for u_int64_t type in sys/bitypes.h... nochecking for uintXX_t types... yeschecking for uintXX_t types in stdint.h... yeschecking for u_char... yeschecking for socklen_t... yeschecking for sig_atomic_t... yeschecking for fsblkcnt_t... yeschecking for fsfilcnt_t... yeschecking for in_addr_t... yeschecking for in_port_t... yeschecking for size_t... yeschecking for ssize_t... yeschecking for clock_t... yeschecking for sa_family_t... yeschecking for pid_t... yeschecking for mode_t... yeschecking for struct sockaddr_storage... yeschecking for struct sockaddr_in6... yeschecking for struct in6_addr... yeschecking for struct sockaddr_in6.sin6_scope_id... yeschecking for struct addrinfo... yeschecking for struct timeval... yeschecking for struct timespec... yeschecking for ut_host field in utmp.h... nochecking for ut_host field in utmpx.h... yeschecking for syslen field in utmpx.h... yeschecking for ut_pid field in utmp.h... yeschecking for ut_type field in utmp.h... yeschecking for ut_type field in utmpx.h... yeschecking for ut_tv field in utmp.h... nochecking for ut_id field in utmp.h... yeschecking for ut_id field in utmpx.h... yeschecking for ut_addr field in utmp.h... nochecking for ut_addr field in utmpx.h... nochecking for ut_addr_v6 field in utmp.h... nochecking for ut_addr_v6 field in utmpx.h... nochecking for ut_exit field in utmp.h... yeschecking for ut_time field in utmp.h... yeschecking for ut_time field in utmpx.h... yeschecking for ut_tv field in utmpx.h... yeschecking for struct stat.st_blksize... yeschecking for struct __res_state.retrans... yeschecking for ss_family field in struct sockaddr_storage... yeschecking for __ss_family field in struct sockaddr_storage... nochecking for pw_class field in struct passwd... nochecking for pw_expire field in struct passwd... nochecking for pw_change field in struct passwd... nochecking for msg_accrights field in struct msghdr... yeschecking if struct statvfs.f_fsid is integral type... yeschecking for msg_control field in struct msghdr... nochecking if libc defines __progname... yeschecking whether gcc implements __FUNCTION__... yeschecking whether gcc implements __func__... yeschecking whether va_copy exists... yeschecking whether __va_copy exists... yeschecking whether getopt has optreset support... nochecking if libc defines sys_errlist... yeschecking if libc defines sys_nerr... yeschecking for library containing getrrsetbyname... nochecking for library containing res_query... -lresolvchecking for library containing dn_expand... none requiredchecking if res_query will link... yeschecking for _getshort... yeschecking for _getlong... yeschecking whether _getshort is declared... nochecking whether _getlong is declared... nochecking for HEADER.ad... nochecking if struct __res_state _res is an extern... yeschecking for xauth... nochecking Discovering system mail directory... Using: /var/mail from _PATH_MAILDIRchecking for "/dev/ptmx"... yeschecking for "/dev/ptc"... nochecking for nroff... (cached) /usr/gnu/bin/nroffchecking if the systems has expire shadow information... yeschecking for "/etc/default/login"... yesconfigure: WARNING:If PATH is defined in /etc/default/login, ensure the path to scp is included,otherwise scp will not work.Adding /usr/local/bin to USER_PATH so scp will workchecking if we need to convert IPv4 in IPv6-mapped addresses... no (default)checking if your system defines LASTLOG_FILE... nochecking if your system defines _PATH_LASTLOG... nochecking if your system defines UTMP_FILE... yeschecking if your system defines WTMP_FILE... yeschecking if your system defines WTMPX_FILE... yeschecking whether BROKEN_GETADDRINFO is declared... noconfigure: creating ./config.statusconfig.status: creating Makefileconfig.status: creating buildpkg.shconfig.status: creating opensshd.initconfig.status: creating openssh.xmlconfig.status: creating openbsd-compat/Makefileconfig.status: creating openbsd-compat/regress/Makefileconfig.status: creating survey.shconfig.status: creating config.hconfig.status: config.h is unchangedOpenSSH has been configured with the following options:                     User binaries: /usr/local/bin                   System binaries: /usr/local/sbin               Configuration files: /usr/local/etc                   Askpass program: /usr/local/libexec/ssh-askpass                      Manual pages: /usr/local/share/man/manX                          PID file: /var/run  Privilege separation chroot path: /var/empty            sshd default user PATH: /usr/ccs/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin   (If PATH is set in /etc/default/login it will be used instead. If   used, ensure the path to scp is present, otherwise scp will not work.)                    Manpage format: doc                       PAM support: no                   OSF SIA support: no                 KerberosV support: no                   SELinux support: no                 Smartcard support:                      S/KEY support: no              TCP Wrappers support: no              MD5 password support: no                   libedit support: no  Solaris process contract support: no           Solaris project support: no       IP address in $DISPLAY hack: no           Translate v4 in v6 hack: no                  BSD Auth support: no              Random number source: OpenSSL internal ONLY             Privsep sandbox style: none              Host: i386-pc-solaris2.11          Compiler: gcc    Compiler flags: -g -O2 -Wall -Wpointer-arith -Wuninitialized -Wsign-compare -Wformat-security -Wno-pointer-sign -fno-strict-aliasing -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-builtin-memset -fstack-protector-all Preprocessor flags:       Linker flags:  -fstack-protector-all         Libraries: -lresolv -lcrypto -lz -lsocket -lnslSVR4 style packages are supported with "make package"
```

Comment: А pkginfo не? И кста какой еще aptitude на solaris???

Comment: @pyatak я новичок в `linux`, поэтому не могли бы вы мне подсказать как пользоваться `pkginfo` для определения установленности вышеуказанных пакетов?

Comment: pkginfo покажет список пакетов в системе. Выхлоп отфильтруйте грепом pkginfo | grep -i openssl. И почитайте про инструменты pkginfo, pkgchk без этих инструментов вам все равно не обойтись новичку.

Comment: @pyatak `pkginfo | grep -i openssl` ничего не выдало, хотя `openssl` установлен как показано в сообщениях    checking OpenSSL header version... 1000004f (OpenSSL 1.0.0d 8 Feb 2011)    checking OpenSSL library version... 1000004f (OpenSSL 1.0.0d 8 Feb 2011)    checking whether OpenSSL's headers match the library... yes    checking if programs using OpenSSL functions will link... yes    checking whether OpenSSL has crippled AES support... no    checking whether OpenSSL has complete ECC support... no    checking whether OpenSSL's PRNG is internally seeded... yes

Comment: pkginfo | grep -i ssl ?

Comment: вообще после запуска  просто `pkginfo`, как и `pkginfo | grep -i ssl` ничего не отображется.

Answer (score 1):

В вашем же списке:

```
...checking zlib.h usability... yeschecking zlib.h presence... yeschecking for zlib.h... yeschecking for deflate in -lz... yeschecking for possibly buggy zlib... no...checking OpenSSL header version... 1000004f (OpenSSL 1.0.0d 8 Feb 2011)checking OpenSSL library version... 1000004f (OpenSSL 1.0.0d 8 Feb 2011)...
```

Answer (score 1):

стандартно в solaris для этого есть pkginfo

```
/usr/bin/pkginfo
```

можно установить pkgutil, если необходимо устанавливать новые пакеты (это если не хочешь скомпилить пакет сам =))
Для  solaris 10  и 11:

```
pkgadd -d http://get.opencsw.org/now
/opt/csw/bin/pkgutil -U
/opt/csw/bin/pkgutil -y -i pkgutil 
/usr/sbin/pkgchk -L CSWpkgutil # list files
```

дальше с помощью этой улилиты можешь смотреть, устанавливать и т.д пакеты.

```
pkgutil --list
```

Answer (score 0):

а ОС какая? Попробуй - whereis openssl

Comment: в результате выполнения    bash: whereis: command not found.OC - `nexenta`.

Answer (score 0):

Можно ещё вот так:dpkg --get-slections | grep ssl